# Same quadratic forms on $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, quadratic-forms

Let $q$ be an inner product on $\mathbb R^n$ and $Q$ be its matrix expressed in the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^n$.

Assume that the group $$SO(q)=\{A\in M_n(\mathbb R) \ | \ A^TQA=Q\}$$ of matrices with positive determinant preserving the quadratic form $q$ is equal to $SO(n,\mathbb R)$.

Is it true that $q$ is the canonical scalar product on $\mathbb R^n$ ? Is it possible to recover the orthogonal group of $q$ just from $SO(q)$ ?

Comment: Do you mean, is it possible to recover the scalar product from $SO(q)$?

Comment: What does $A$ have to do with $M$ in your set notation? (Must be a typo somewhere. $A^TQA$ maybe?)

Comment: Yes, thank you it's a typo.

Comment: @Travis: not exactly, I am asking if two inner product having the same special orthogonal group are the same or proportional in some way.

Comment: @user141753 Yes, if $SO(q) = SO(q')$, then $q$ and $q'$ are (nonzero) multiples of one another.

Comment: @Travis: Do you have any references of this fact for general quadratic forms ?

Comment: Given a copy of $SO(q)$ one can pick any nonzero vector, declare it to have length $1$ (thus fixing the scale), and then inductively choose elements of a basis orthonormal with respect to that scale. In that basis, the quadratic form has matrix representation $I$, and you can apply the second half of @Daniel's argument. If q is indefinite and nondegenerate, there is a cone of null vectors, and this too determines $q$ up to scale. (I claim this, by the way, only over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$; I'm not sure whether the claim is true for $q$ on vector spaces over finite fields.)

Comment: @Travis: Thank you Travis, I will try it.

Comment: @Travis: Do you know if such a result would be also true if $q$ is only non-degenerate instead of being a inner product ?

Comment: Yes, provided that the form is symmetric. That's what I meant by "indefinite and nondegerate"---in that case, the quadratic form (again, up to an overall constant) is determined by its cone of null vectors.

Comment: I am not sure to well understand your argument then, for example how do you manage the case $q(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $q'$ any other quadratic form such that $SO(q)=SO(q')$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17374/discussion-between-user141753-and-travis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $SO(q)=SO(n,\mathbb{R})$ then every $A\in SO(q)$ satisfy $A^tA=AA^t=Id$.
Thus, $QA=AQ$ for every $A\in SO(n)$.

Let $v$ be a normalized eigenvector of the symmetric matrix $Q$ associated to the eigenvalue $a$.

Let $w$ be any normalized vector of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is always possible to find a matrix $A\in SO(n)$ such that $Av=w$.

Notice that $Qw=QAv=AQv=aAv=aw$. Thus, any $w\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is an eigenvector of $Q$ associated to $a$. Thus, $Q=aId$.